# Architecture for html5 multiplayer game?

Tags: architecture, multiplayer, html5

Hello I want to write a HTML5 multiplayer game in which there are rooms with two players answering a series of questions with 3 possible answers, 10sec/question, which are being downloaded from a server. It will have some ratings and so on.

I want to make it as scalable as possible.
I wonder what technologies to use to accomplish that. HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript obviously. But what about the server-side? I have been researching and found that Socket.IO + Node.js + mongoDB would do the job but after doing some more research it maybe not.

Can you suggest me some kind of architecture for doing this game? Free technologies, if possible. Or what to read and from where to start in order to understand how to do it.

Thanx in advance!

P.S. I have an experience with HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, C#, ASP.NET MVC and relational db's.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be "that guy", but check out BrowserQuest.

https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest/
http://browserquest.mozilla.org/

Check out how Mozilla does, you might be able to learn a thing or two!

Answer (score 1):

Also see GRITS: PvP Gaming with HTML5

Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Prkyd5n0P7k

Source:
http://code.google.com/p/gritsgame/

Comment: Maybe a bad example, because it only runs on Chrome ... "Sorry, this page is optimized for Desktop versions of Chrome."

Comment: Their sample page pops up with an error